# Photoshop: Edgy stroke on a perfecly round object

Tags: adobe-photoshop, stroke, layer-style

I'm using the latest version of Photoshop on Mac OS and I have a problem with the stroke effect in Layer Style. Even when I use it on a perfectly round object in high resolution (the example below is ~1800x800px) the stroke comes out awfully edgy:

[image: Edgy stroke effect on a perfectly round font]

And here I applied a 225px stroke on a perfectly round circle:
[image: Stroke on a circle]

**What can be the reason of it and do you have any idea can I fix this?**

Answer (score 2):

Fixing solution:

1 - Right click on the text layer and convert it to a shape layer

[image: shape]

2 - Select the Shape Selection Tool from the Tool Palette

[image: tool]

3 - On the top options choose the stroke color of the shape, the size and the exterior position on Align

[image: align]

4 - Ready!

[image: end]

Answer (score 0):

**Why** this happens....

There's a point where the sections of the original shape start to collide with each other. I.E. the stroke on the top of the "s" starts to overlap the stroke on the left side of the "s". This is a sort of "miter limit" to the applied stroke. Once you pass that limit you start seeing angles or "bumps" which are an indication of a overlapping limit area.

This is why a 10pt stroke is fine, but a 20pt stroke may look horrible.

Ideally, if you need that large of a stroke on an object, an alternative construction method is better than using the layer style stroke.