# What's this text effect name? Any tips for doing this?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, style-identification

I saw this on the web, and was wondering if anyone have some experience on how to do it!
It might be a well-known effect but I have no idea about it.

[image]

Comment: Hi, could you please [edit] your question to show your own work so we can see where you got stuck.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Traditionally I've always heard such art called **Contour Drawings**.

It's merely a series of lines that follow the contour of a shape.

There's no *automated* method in any application to create this which I'm aware of. However, Applying a series of ever-expanding lines is a fairly easy thing to do in Adobe Illustrator.

[image]

In fact, with the proper set up, you can merely use a **blend** in Illustrator to create all the lines in one step.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

- I would say **Op Art**
- Shutterstock/Google say **Concentric Oncoming**
- In the book *Principles of Two-Dimensional Design* by Wucius Wong it's called **Concentric Repetition**

In Photoshop, from a **Shape Layer**, select it with the **Shape Selector Tool** 
 [image: selector]

**1** - Add a **White Stroke** aligned outside:

[image: stroke]

**2** - Add an **Outside Black Stroke Effect** to the layer:

[image: first]

**3** - Duplicating the layer, change the **Shape Stroke Width** on each lower layer:

[image: final]

Comment: That does work with a shape, however, I think that is a calligraphic letterform in the example.

Comment: @NormanEdward See here: https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/109090/photoshop-edgy-stroke-on-a-perfecly-round-object/109091#109091

Answer (score 0):

Use black and white sequential outlining under Edit. You can switch between sizes and black and white beginning at the center, the effect can be achieved by alternating color and width. (This is a low res example.)

[image: Happy]

Comment: Any chance you know what it's called?

Comment: @LateralTerminal I would say **Op Art**, but Shutterstock/Google says **Concentric Oncoming**.

Comment: @lateralTerminal What Daniello suggests, or, **Concentric Shaping**